# Repeat (ng-repeat) items and have a user enter a QTY for each item and submit ALL the form data (existing repeated items + QTY) in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

As per the title, my question is: **How can I repeat (ng-repeat) pre-selected items and have a user enter a QTY for each item in a following step and submit ALL the form data (existing repeated items + QTY) in AngularJs?**

I assume one could perhaps add `$index` to an item being repeated? Or there might be a much better and easier solution I am missing.

**This is what I am trying to achieve:**
After a user has selected items to add to a quote (no additional input such as QTY), the selected items are then repeated in a next step in the "Quote" view, where a customer must be able to enter a QTY for each quoted item. All the data must then be sent to the controller when the client click on NEXT.

I have played around with the following by repeating each item in a form (but disabling the data I do not want the customer to mess with), and having an input for the QTY. But the result of this is obviously that the QTY entered for a item sets all the QTYs to the same amount. Also, the data being passed on `ng-click="next(quoteFormData)"`, only contains the single QTY value, and not all the data:

```
<div class="container-fluid" ng-show="showQuote">
    <form name="createNewQuoteForm" method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="item in quote">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input ng-model="quoteFormData.productId" type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="" placeholder="{{item.productId}}" ng-disabled="true">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input ng-model="quoteFormData.productName" type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="" placeholder="{{item.productName}}" ng-disabled="true">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input ng-model="quoteFormData.supplierName" type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="" placeholder="{{item.supplierName}}" ng-disabled="true">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <input ng-model="quoteFormData.qty" type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="" placeholder="0">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="next(quoteFormData)" ng-show="showNext">Next</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have also tried a similar approach using a table to repeat the data, and having an input field for the QTY, but I did not manage to get ANY data sent that way.

Comment: This might be the most detailed question title I've ever seen...

Comment: why can't you just bind ng-model to each object with a property like `orderQty`? Really not clear what specific problem is about sending the data. Create a plunker demo

Comment: @charlietfl I am trying this in the Quote step. But I think this is not working because of the `ng-disable` in the repeated items. Also, the idea is that a user can simply tap (using a phone) or click on an item to add it to the quote, and then at a later stage have the customer add the QTY.

Comment: Instead of binding on quoteFormData properties (ng-model) try binding on item (item in quote). Then in de ng-click: next(quote)

Comment: @E.Mourits Holy crap! It works! I have NEVER tried it this way before. You learn something every day. :D Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

*Posting my comment as answer (for anybody running across this question in the future).*

Instead of binding on quoteFormData properties (ng-model) try binding on item (item in quote). Then in de ng-click: next(quote)

```
<div class="container-fluid" ng-show="showQuote">
<form name="createNewQuoteForm" method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="item in quote">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input ng-model="item.productId" type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="" placeholder="{{item.productId}}" ng-disabled="true">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input ng-model="item.productName" type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="" placeholder="{{item.productName}}" ng-disabled="true">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input ng-model="item.supplierName" type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="" placeholder="{{item.supplierName}}" ng-disabled="true">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <input ng-model="item.qty" type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="" placeholder="0">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="next(quote)" ng-show="showNext">Next</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did my implementation slightly different, but I expect the results would be the same. I did the binding on the `form-group` itself, and simply bound the QTY field with `ng-model="item.qty"`. Also, I pass the `quote` when submitting the `form`:

```
<div class="container-fluid" ng-show="showQuote">
    <form name="createNewQuoteForm" method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="item in quote" ng-model="item">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="" placeholder="{{item.productId}}" ng-disabled="true">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="" placeholder="{{item.productName}}" ng-disabled="true">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="" placeholder="{{item.supplierName}}" ng-disabled="true">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="item.qty" class="form-control" id="" name="" placeholder="0">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="next(quote)" ng-show="showNext">Next</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>
```